# Check dates overlap within 3 months

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table as below:

```
Cola    REF     RecordNumber    StartDate               EndDate             
NAME1   REF001  RECORD011       12/11/2012              11/01/2013     
NAME1   REF001  RECORD012       24/01/2013              10/04/2013  
NAME1   REF001  RECORD013       26/04/2013               9/07/2013     
NAME1   REF001  RECORD014       12/06/2013               2/07/2013  
NAME1   REF001  RECORD015       11/07/2013              17/07/2013      
NAME1   REF001  RECORD016       2/09/2013               23/09/2013   
NAME1   REF001  RECORD017       26/04/2013              6/09/2013
```

I need to return any rows where:

- the cola is the same
- ref is the same
- start date or end date are    within 3 months of any other
  recordnumber - so any that overlap are included also

so far I have this which I believe sorts out the top 2:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Cola
              , Ref
              , RecordNumber
              , StartDate
              , EndDate
FROM datatable a
WHERE EXISTS 
    (
    SELECT TOP 1 1 
    FROM datatable b 
    WHERE b.cola = a.cola 
            AND b.ref = a.ref 
            AND b.id <> a.id)
```

I'm struggling on the date check part though, can anyone point me in the right direction?

I think I should end up with

```
Cola    REF     RecordNumber    StartDate               EndDate             
NAME1   REF001  RECORD011       12/11/2012              11/01/2013         
NAME1   REF001  RECORD014       12/06/2013               2/07/2013       
NAME1   REF001  RECORD017       26/04/2013               6/09/2013
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add date arithmetic to the subquery.  Here is an example:

```
SELECT dt.*
FROM datatable dt
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
              FROM datatable dt2 
              WHERE dt2.cola = dt.cola AND
                    dt2.ref = dt.ref AND
                    dt2.id <> dt.id AND
                    (dt.startdate between dateadd(month, -3, dt2.startdate) and
                                          dateadd(month, 3, dt2.enddate) or
                     dt.enddate between dateadd(month, -3, dt2.startdate) and
                                        dateadd(month, 3, dt2.enddate)
                    )
             );
```

Comment: This is bringing back all rows still?